# Simple past of the verb subset

Tags: simple-past

What is the simple past of the verb *to subset*?  The simple past of *set* is *set*.   But, I see it written as *subsetted*, as in:

> Each row in the matrix specifies the location of one value, where each column corresponds to a dimension in the array being subsetted."

This is from *Advanced R*,  by Hadley Wickham.

Comment: There is no such verb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word *subset* comes from the noun *set*, meaning collection of things. This is completely unrelated to the verb *set*, both in meaning and [etymologically.](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=set) The noun comes from Latin, while the verb comes from Old English.  So why should the verb *subset* follow the conjugation of the unrelated verb *set*?

You might just as easily ask why the verb *pellet* has a past tense of *pelleted*, when the past tense of *let* is *let*. It's because they're completely unrelated.

Comment: Analogy. *Dove* is now an accepted past tense of *dive* and *proven* a long-standing accepted past participle of *prove*, both of which came about by analogy - what marks *subset* as different that it can't be subject a similar innovation?

Comment: @Anonym: I suppose it could have, but mathematicians use *subsetted* as the past tense of *subset*.

Comment: This looks like the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

*Subset* is not a verb according to every major English dictionary.

If you wanted to use the word as a verb in nonstandard usage, we can look at how similar sounding words are formed in the simple past to try to hazard a guess.

The [simple past](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/offset) of *offset* is *offset.*

The [simple past](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/reset) of *reset* is *reset*.

The [simple past](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/upset) of *upset* is *upset*.

The [simple past](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/Typeset) of *typeset* is *typeset*.

The [simple past](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/preset) of *preset* is *preset*.

The [simple past](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/overset) of *overset* is *overset*.

The [simple past](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/beset) of *beset* is *beset*.

The [simple past](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/underset) of *underset* is *underset*.

So I would propose that the simple past of *subset* is *subset.*

To me, *subsetted* sounds unnatural.

Comment: Yes, but "*... where each column corresponds to a dimension in the array being subset.*" sounds *more* unnatural.

Comment: The past tense of *let* is *let*, the past tense of *sublet* is *sublet*, the past tense of *relet* is *relet*, but the past tense of *pellet* is *pelleted* and the past tense of *leaflet* is *leafleted*. The meaning makes a difference. And *subset* has nothing to do with the verb *set*.

Comment: @PeterShor And I guess all of the examples in Kyle's list are based on the verb *set*. Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

A "set being subsetted" is properly called a *superset*—also not a verb.

But you should, alas, feel free to say "subsetted" if it gets the point across in a programming situation.  Without liberties like these we wouldn't have many manuals at all.

In your example, better ways to get the point across could be by saying "source set," "original set" or "input set."